# Using ASP.NET mobile choose an existing photo, iPhone picture capture

Tags: html, iphone, mobile, camera, photo

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

Using this file input using iPhone safari used to display an option to the select a photo from the existing photo from the library or the Camera. Now in iOS10+ it just goes to the camera, wihtout the options.

I assume its a security option which needs to enabled, but we're using asp.net so we can't add the option to enable access.

Is there any way of allowing the user to access existing Photos to upload, using asp.net alone?

Answer (score 1):

Worked this out in the end, just needed to remove the capture attribute, which then provide the options of picking existing or taking a new photo. not sure which iOS version this changed.